# Can't copy schema data in /mySql Workbench 6.0

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-workbench

I've just installed MySql Workbench 6.0.09 on recommendation. The main reason was to copy my Wordpress database which is stored in MySql.

I'm using the import/export function with a single file, however it doesn't seem to populate the new schema whether I create it before hand or let the process create it.

I've read somewhere that this cross schema copy doesn't work in older versions, but I'm unsure whether this is still the case, i'm doing something wrong, or there is a permissions issue. It seems unlikely that I'm doing something wrong as there is literally a few clicks to deal with.

Anyone advise?

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant from 1 schema to another. I want to retain my original WP schema as is and create another for the new website.

Comment: But you're just making a backup. This is trivial and should work fine in Workbench. How is your site hosted, because most hosts include features for creating backups.

Comment: The site is on our own Windows Server. I literally want to create another database not back a database intended for restoration to the same place.

Comment: It's the same. You're (normally) just exporting an SQL file - a simple set of DDLs (CREATE and INSERT statements, as well as any Stored Procedures and VIEWS). You can use this as a backup or a copy, or print it out and wrap your fish and chips up in it. Ah, unless your Windows Server uses M$SQL !?!?

Comment: Yes you're right. At this point I would like to point out that my SQL or MySQL skills are not that great - hence using a product like workbench to simplify stuff. It does have an import/export function but its not working as expected. There is an option to import into a new schema but whatever I do it gets restored back to the original schema.

Comment: I've not used Workbench (although I only hear good things about it - just got used to using the command line I guess), so I can't help further, but maybe others can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an answer to this however, I did work out a solution.

1) I took a backup of the existing database.
2) I edited the script produced by the backup. I edited the database name on 2 lines at the top of the script then ran it.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion above I conclude this question is about creating a duplicate of an existing database using MySQL Workbench. There are several possible approaches for this scenario:

1. Createa a dump of your source server using the Data Export feature in MySQL Workbench:
   [image]. Then restore that dump on the target machine (via `Data Import/Restore`).
2. Do a quick an easy shot by using Schema Transfer Wizard. See `menu -> Database -> Schema Transfer Wizard...`
3. Start a normal MySQL to MySQL migration using the Migration Wizard under the same menu item. This would also allow to migrate to different MySQL versions.